# Fetch the id of the country dynamically in the URL after click on submit button or search button

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is controller.php

```
 <?php
class Autocomplete extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('datacomplete');
    }
    public function index($id)
    {
        echo $id;
        $this->load->view('view_demo', $data);
    }
    public function GetCountryName()
    {
        $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
        $data    = $this->datacomplete->GetRow($keyword);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
?>
```

This is a model

```
<?php
class Datacomplete extends CI_Model
{

    public function GetRow($keyword)
    {
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        $this->db->like("name", $keyword);

        return $this->db->get('autocomplete')->result_array();
    }

}
```

this is view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/custom.js">
    </script>
    </link>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #000000;">
    <?php echo $id= 1; ?>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url('autocomplete/index/' .$id); ?>" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <center>
                <h2 style="color: #fff;">
                    AUTOCOMPLETE FORM FROM DATABASE USING CODEIGNITER AND AJAX
                </h2>
            </center>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="margin-top: 200px;">
                <label class="control-lable" style="color: #fff;">
                    Country Name
                </label>
                <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="country" name="country" placeholder="Type to get an Ajax call of Countries" style="height:70px" type="text">
                <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" class="dropdown-menu txtcountry" id="DropdownCountry" role="menu" style="margin-left:15px;margin-right:0px;">
                </ul>
                <input type="submit">
                </input>
                </input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

This is custom.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#country").keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/codeajax/autocomplete/GetCountryName",
            data: {
                keyword: $("#country").val()
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $('#DropdownCountry').empty();
                    $('#country').attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                    $('#DropdownCountry').dropdown('toggle');
                } else if (data.length == 0) {
                    $('#country').attr("data-toggle", "");
                }
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    if (data.length >= 0)
                        $('#DropdownCountry').append('<li role="displayCountries" ><a role="menuitem dropdownCountryli" class="dropdownlivalue">' + value['name'] + '</a></li>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
    $('ul.txtcountry').on('click', 'li a', function() {
        $('#country').val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

I want to fetch the id of the country dynamically in the URL after clicking the submit button.
Now I have this using static passing id as 1.
the table has two column id and name of the country.
how to pass the id dynamically to url when I click the submit button.
I m failing to fetch the id dynamically from database ie  when I click on submit should redirect to the  new page with country id or echo $id in the new page as well as to the URL it should show me id of the country

Comment: Are you getting an error? what is stopping you from taking id?

Comment: @M.Hemant i have fetch the id but it is static ....but i want to fetch the country id ie id dynamiccally....and i dont't know how to fetch the id dynamically after click on submit button

Comment: first, where is your submit button? second, when you hit submit then where it goes? when you submit do have `$id` in that form?

Comment: @M.Hemant  i have submit button like this                 <input type="submit"> and it is in above code ...when i click on submit it redirect to new page or empty page  and you make new page with any name ....and in form i have this code <form  action="<?php echo base_url('autocomplete/index/' .$id); ?>" method="post">

Comment: @M.Hemant i have a search bar where i serach for india in search and when i click on submit button it take the id of the country india to new page in URL  echo base_url('autocomplete/index/' .$id); and also echo the id in the page .I have to do two thing first pass id of india in the URL and then echo the id on the same page ie echo $id;

Comment: @DEEWAAKARKUMAR  `the table has two column id and name of the country` what is the table name and I didn't find any code for fetching data for $id from your code.

Comment: @RasaMohamed tabel name is autocomplete

Comment: @RasaMohamed   i have index function in controller for id

Comment: Hi @DEEWAAKARKUMAR, have you try my answer?

Comment: @HastaDhana Thanks for asking ....i have tried but it is not working ....can u please check the controller ,method and view file and then give me proper answer

Comment: @HastaDhana if u can send me ur email id i will send the whole project to u.....its is just small task ...just hardly will take 15 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it using javascript.

First change the form :

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('autocomplete/index/' .$id); ?>" method="post">
```

To :

```
<form method="post" id="countryForm">
```

Then change the submit button :

```
<input type="submit">
```

To :

```
<input type="submit" id="submitForm" disabled>
```

And then apply the following javascript codes :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#country").keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/codeajax/autocomplete/GetCountryName",
            data: {
                keyword: $("#country").val()
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $('#DropdownCountry').empty();
                    $('#country').attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                    $('#DropdownCountry').dropdown('toggle');
                } else if (data.length == 0) {
                    $('#country').attr("data-toggle", "");
                }
                // Assign each country id into each country list `data-` element
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    if (data.length >= 0)
                        $('#DropdownCountry').append('<li role="displayCountries" ><a role="menuitem dropdownCountryli" data-countryid="' + value['id'] + '" class="dropdownlivalue">' + value['name'] + '</a></li>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
    $('ul.txtcountry').on('click', 'li a', function() {
        $('#country').val($(this).text());
        $('#countryForm').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url('autocomplete/index/'); ?>' + $(this).data('countryid'); // set new form action which contain country id
        $('#submitForm').removeAttr('disabled'); // enable the submit button after one country is selected
    });
});
```